# Get all customers by the specific zip code

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, sql

Help me please to write a SQL query that returns the customer ID of addresses that contain the "@" symbol in the zip code field. Or just tell me which tables magento uses to keep zip codes.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/address_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('postcode', array('like' => '%@%'));

var_dump($collection->getColumnValues('parent_id'));
// or
foreach ($collection as $address) {
    var_dump($address->getData()); // complete address data
    var_dump($address->getData('parent_id')) // customer ID only
}
```

To get the SQL query:

```
echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();
```

Results in:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `at_postcode`.`value` AS `postcode` FROM 
`prefix_customer_address_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `prefix_customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_postcode` ON (`at_postcode`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`)AND (`at_postcode`.`attribute_id` = '30')
WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '2') AND (at_postcode.value LIKE '%@%')
```